# Search between dates and times in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to search between dates and times.

For example, between `date: 30/02/2007, time: 10:32` and `date: 21/06/2008, time: 14:19`

What is the most simple query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should look at the date time formats available in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi` is what you should use:

try:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM Records
    WHERE DateCreated>='2007-02-30 10:32' AND DateCreated<='2008-06-21 14:19'
```

in the above query the strings will be converted to datetime data type if `DateCreated` is a datetime column. and the query will work.

you can create local variables of datetime data type and use a query like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

SELECT @StartDate='2007-02-30 10:32', @EndDate='2008-06-21 14:19'

SELECT
    *
    FROM Records
    WHERE DateCreated>=@StartDate AND DateCreated<=@EndDate
```

I like using <, <=, >=, or > because it allows more flexibility than `BETWEEN` and forces you to think about including endpoints or not.

Another thing to consider is getting all data from a complete day:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

--set the days you want
SELECT @StartDate='2007-02-30 10:32', @EndDate='2008-06-21 14:19'

--remove the time
SELECT @StartDate=DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@StartDate),0), @EndDate=DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@EndDate),0)

--get everything on '2007-02-30' up to the end of the day on '2008-06-21'
SELECT
    *
    FROM Records
    WHERE DateCreated>=@StartDate AND DateCreated<@EndDate+1
```

Comment: It has been almost a decade and nobody bothered to correct this? Damn you, SO! It's `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` :P

Comment: you can always edit the answer, can't you? @AswinRamakrishnan

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Records
WHERE
    DateCreated BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
```

Comment: thank's for the help, but how to write the date & time ? date: 30/02/2007, time: 10:32 and date: 21/06/2008, time: 14:19

Comment: In the above example the @Date1 and @Date2 variables are of type datetime
This means that you can assign date and time to them like this:

`DECLARE @Date1 datetime
SET @Date1 = '2010-03-18 10:52'`