# Conditional where statement: select different time period when query date varies

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I have a query need to select different time period. The logic is:

- if today is Tuesday, select Saturday 00:00:00 ~ Monday 23:99;
- if today is other weekdays, select the previous working day (00:00:00 ~ 23:99).

Here is the query I have:

```
Select *
From ...
WHERE 
    (DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())= 'Tuesday'
    AND (<@SalesDate> BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())))
OR
    (DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())<> 'Tuesday'
    AND (<@SalesDate> BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())and DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())))
```

It didn't return the result that I want. Anyone can help me? thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, it is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3349.0 (X64)   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is a bit finicky when it comes to date datatypes. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099364/sql-server-fetching-records-between-two-dates).

`GETDATE()` will return the time for today. You need to strips it off.

```
-- Today's date, stripped of time
DECLARE @Today datetime = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))

Select *
From ...
WHERE 
    (DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())= 'Tuesday'
    AND (@SalesDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, @Today) and @SalesDate < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Today)))
OR
    (DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())<> 'Tuesday'
    AND (@SalesDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Today) and @SalesDate < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Today)))
```