# between statement not working properly in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo, between

I m using the 'BETWEEN' statement in php data objects to show posts made between 2 specific dates, but however, 'date from' is not working, although 'date to' is working properly, if I only set 'date from', nothing is displayed, but if I only set 'date to', correct posts are displayed, also if I set both 'date from' and 'date to', still correct posts are displayed, the problem is only when I select only 'date from', This is my code

```
$dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Main_Posts_table WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo' ";
$data = $connect->query($sql);
echo "<center><table class = 'main_table'>";
foreach($data as $row){
echo "<tr><td><span id = 'time_of_post'>".$row['time']."</span><br/><br/>".$row['posts']."<br/><br/><span id = 'comment_button'>comments &#8609;</span></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table></center>";
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `time` column?

Comment: the type is datetime @hassan

Comment: Please show sample Data and Output you get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : fetching records between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099364/sql-server-fetching-records-between-two-dates)

Comment: This is mysql not sql server, I tagged it mysql

Comment: seems a logical issue .. if you don't set dateTo then you are searching  between   a valid date and null .. null is converted  in the beginning mysql date .. and then the query not retunr values because the end date is less the start date

Comment: I did thought about the same, so that means, I will have to make a separate if-else block where dateto is not set and datefrom is set, then in $sql, I will set 'datefrom' to $datefrom and instead of $dateto, I can set a custom value like 2060-4-4, is this the only way ? @scaisEdge

Comment: yes  both the way are correct .. you can also check if the $dateTo is null then assign tan high  value for your need .

Comment: pdo with no prepared statements... useless

Comment: Since the input type was date, that is why I didn't bother about prepared statements, do I need to prepare the statements even if the input type is date ? @Masivuye Cokile

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
if(empty($_POST['dateTo']) && !empty($_POST['dateFrom'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Main_Posts_table WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '2080-12-31' ";
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Main_Posts_table WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo' ";
}
```

If dateto is not set, it is set to null, a value less than datefrom, so I created a separate if else block, to check for a case where only datefrom is set, and then I set dateto to a very high value, if anyone can think of a shorter code, please post