# How to find dates between two dates in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to find the dates between two dates in SQL Server.

```
where 
    startdate = '2015-12-04 00:00:00.000' 
    and enddate = '2015-12-07 00:00:00.000'
```

Result should be

```
2015-12-04 00:00:00.000
2015-12-05 00:00:00.000
2015-12-06 00:00:00.000
2015-12-07 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is too vague as written.

Comment: Isn't that timestamps, not dates? (Do you expect `2015-12-10 12:00:00.000` to be returned?)

Comment: @Gordon if that question is that simple. USE the search function or just google it!!

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for your comment i need to find the date between these timestamps

Comment: Usually simplest way is to create a calendar table (one day = one row). You can then use it for other purposes too.

Comment: Similar querstions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462738/search-between-dates-and-times-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in sqlserver 2005:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime 

DECLARE @enddate datetime

SELECT @startdate ='2015-12-04', @enddate='2015-12-07'

;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f)
SELECT top (datediff(d, @startdate, @enddate) + 1) 
  dateadd(d, N - 1, @startdate)
FROM tally
```

Result(I removed timepart):

```
2015-12-04
2015-12-05
2015-12-06
2015-12-07
```

Comment: thanks for you wonderful comment ... many thanks it works .. . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '20151204'
SET @Date2 = '20151210'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

Or:

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

select @startDate = '20151204';
select @endDate = '20151210';

with interdate as
(
  select dt = dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate)
  where dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from interdate
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
select *
from interdate
```