# Comparing dates using between results slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, msbi

I am using the next condition in my `where` clause of the query:

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DA.ACCESS_DATE, 112))  
        > = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CCM.START_DATE, 112))
AND 
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DA.ACCESS_DATE, 112)) 
        < ISNULL(convert(int, convert(varchar(10), CCM.[END_DATE], 112)), 20161001)
```

While running the query using above condition it is taking lot of time to return the output.

Is there any way to get the quicker result?

Comment: Do you need to convert the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search between dates and times in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462738/search-between-dates-and-times-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me?  Why would you convert dates to other types for comparisons?  If the dates have no time components, then you can do:

```
DA.ACCESS_DATE >= CCM.START_DATE AND
DA.ACCESS_DATE < COALESCE(CCM.[END_DATE], '20161001')
```

If the dates do have time components and you want to ignore them, then you should convert to `date`, but only to remove the time component.

I should point out that this might not improve performance.  This version has a chance of taking advantage of available indexes -- if they are appropriate.  The use of indexes would speed the query.

Comment: The DA.ACCESS_DATE is of the type Datetime and START_DATE and END_DATE is Date

Comment: Do I need to include the index on both the table, If so then which index clustered or non clustered ?

Comment: @AnkurJain . . . If you have a question about indexing, you should ask *another* question and include the query (or a simplified version of it).  But, for this query, you should try an index on `da(access_date)` and `ccm(start_date, end_date)`.